# PHP - making use of __call function in interface class

Tags: php, oop

Is it okay to make magic function __call as an abstract and include in interface class so that all the implementation classes are bound to include __call function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier to do some testing before you ask whether something can be done.

> ```
> $ php -r '
> abstract class Foo{
>   public abstract function __call($a,$b);
> }
> class Bar extends Foo{}
> '
> PHP Fatal error:  Class Bar contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
> ```
>
> (Foo::__call) in Command line code on line 5
>
> ```
> $ php -r '
> interface Foo{
>   public function __call($a,$b);
> }
> class Bar implements Foo{}
> '
> PHP Fatal error:  Class Bar contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
> ```
>
> (Foo::__call) in Command line code on line 5

Comment: I have already tested.. just curious whether it is the right approach or not to use magic functions like __call as abstract and use in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is the contract that any class that implements it have to fulfill. 
What kind of the contract it would be if the interface will contain __call() method?

Interface is a guarantee that some specified functionality will be implemented by the class. __call() is not a 'specified functionality'. It is rather lack of it.

So, even if it would be possible this is definitely something that you shouldn't do.